# Steps in requesting an API ( HTTP ) and parsing the data Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, json, swift, http

I am trying to use swift to request an API and then parse the data and use
it as I see fit. I have been able to request the API but I am confused about the process.

In Javascript the following steps are involved:

1. Make a HTTP Request ( GET, POST etc )
2. You get data back in JSON form
3. Create a local variable and save the incoming JSON
4. If the incoming JSON is an array then use a for loop to loop through it.
5. If the JSON is a single object then simply use the **"myObject.value"** technique to extract data

Below is the code for my Swift HTTP request. I am getting the data back and it is being saved within "jsonResult" but I can seem to parse the data.

**Can anyone explain what the are main steps involved in making HTTP requests and parsing the data in swift. And when to use NSArray and NSDictionary?**

```
 //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

 import UIKit
 import XCPlayground // add this in


 XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(continueIndefinitely: true)
 let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk"

 NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in
 // Handle result

  println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
  //HOW TO PARSE THE DATA

  }.resume()
```

The println is giving the following OutPut:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's already a lot of similar questions with answers on SO. You can search for `NSJSONSerialization` for example. Or use a third-party library like SwiftyJSON.

Comment: Another good option is JSONModel ( https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/) for parsing JSON response from server side. However, it is available in Objective-C. You need to go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift to user this Objective-C third party library with your swift code.